# AndroidStudio gradle error: "Error:null value in entry: resOutputDir=null"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I had the build/make error

```
Error:null value in entry: resOutputDir=null
```

when building my project in AdroidStudio

Answer (score 14):

The solution was to simply delete the .gradle folder in the root directory. (backup to make sure you don't blow something up).

answer found here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/null-value-in-entry-dependencycachedir-null/19191/3

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this and other Gradle build errors by executing the menu sequence: "Build > Clean Project".

Answer (score 1):

I stuck in the problem like this. What I done is; **Delete the .Gradle Folder From the Project File in the Project location**.

Then Built and Clean the Project. I searched a lot on Google but the Solution I got from a blog is...

Delete .Gradle Folder -> Clean->Built

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a typo in the variable. domain instead of Domain.